# One-hot encoding when data is stored across multiple columns

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding

Say I have a dataframe

| primary_color | secondary_color | tertiary_color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | blue | green |
| yellow | red | NA |

and i want this to encode by checking if the color exists across any of the three columns (1) or none of the 3 columns (0).  So, it should yield

| red | blue | green | yellow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I'm working in R.  I know I could do this by writing out a bunch of ifelse statements for each color, but my actual problem has a lot more colors.  Is there a more concise way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You may create a new column with row number to track each row, get the data in long format and bring it back to wide by counting occurrence of each color.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = value, id_cols = row, 
              values_fn = length, values_fill = 0) %>%
  select(-row)

#    red  blue green yellow
#  <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#1     1     1     1      0
#2     1     1     0      1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(primary_color = c("red", "yellow"), secondary_color = 
c("blue", "red"), tertiary_color = c("green", "blue")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R you could use `sapply` with a function that checks the vector of desired names:

```
nnames <- c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow")

new_df <- t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)),
                   function(x)(nnames %in% df[x, ]) * 1))

colnames(new_df) <- nnames

#  red blue green yellow
#1   1    1     1      0
#2   1    0     0      1
```

Note if you didnt care about the order of the columns in the second table, you could generalize `nnames` to `nnames <- unique(unlist(df[!is.na(df)]))`

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "primary_color  secondary_color tertiary_color
red blue    green
yellow  red NA", h = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
 mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1)))
   blue green red yellow
V1    1     1   1      0
V2    1     0   1      1
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
table(c(row(df1)), unlist(df1))
     blue green red yellow
  1    1     1   1      0
  2    1     0   1      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `outer`.

```
uc <- unique(unlist(dat))[c(1, 3, 4, 2)]
t(+outer(uc, asplit(dat, 1), Vectorize(`%in%`))) |> `colnames<-`(uc)
#      red blue green yellow
# [1,]   1    1     1      0
# [2,]   1    0     0      1
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(primary_color = c("red", "yellow"), secondary_color = c("blue", 
"red"), tertiary_color = c("green", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

in base R:

```
table(row(df), as.matrix(df))
   
    blue green red yellow
  1    1     1   1      0
  2    0     0   1      1
```

If you want it as a data.frame:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(row(df), as.matrix(df)))

  blue green red yellow
1    1     1   1      0
2    0     0   1      1
```

If there is one color in many columns of the same row:

```
 +(table(row(df), as.matrix(df))>0)
   
    blue green red yellow
  1    1     1   1      0
  2    0     0   1      1
```